# In Java, if a null pointer happes very seldom is it better to use catch instead of if

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

Cleaning up some loose in my Android apps I found a null pointer exception in the developers console which never happened to be and my guess it is a rare race condition.

For those who don't know: Android allows the user to report crashes (i.E. uncaught exception) back to the developer.

I already started to type the infamous `if (… != null)` when it occurred to me: **There are only three reports.** So it happens very seldom.

So I wonder: In this situation, and performance wise: **Would it not be better to catch the null pointer exception instead?**

Considering that the if will be evaluated every time.

Answer (score 8):

Not to sound like a fanatic or narrow-minded person, but I strongly believe **NPE should never be allowed to occur in the first place**! Catching NPE is a very bad practice in my opinion. It means you are not fully aware of how your code is working.

The first thing you should always do before using some input is checking for null.

Comment: +1: its not worth dropping `if (x != null)` on the basis of performance.

Comment: I'd even say not only `NPE` but any `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @AlexR - most modern frameworks use unchecked exceptions these days. These all have to extend `RuntimeException` by design. So it's not necessarily wrong.

Answer (score 3):

How often is "every time" ?  Once per load?  Every minute?  1000 times per second?

In any event, a test for `obj == null` is about as cheap an operation as you can get, and certainly cheaper than exception handling.

And a null pointer exception should never happen - they need to be understood, and prevented.  If you don't know why it's happening, that needs to be fixed.

Comment: «How often is "every time"» – good point. Not hat often actually. But is is more theoretical question for future reference.

Apart from that: I looked for the bug — and I have not got a clue how it is possible. I consider a bug in the VM. In which case it might be better to let the app crash.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions should be used to handle exceptional cases. That is, if it is expected that the value might be null then it is reasonable to check for it rather than catching the exception.
I cannot think of any examples where catching a `NullPointerException` would be better than handling it in the normal control flow.

Comment: When the null to not null ratio is say 10'000 to 1? Would that not be exceptional enough? That is what what I am asking. But maybe this is a http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ question.

Answer (score 0):

If its a multithreaded race condition could it be possible that the variable is being initialized and then set to null again? If so, the "if (... != null)" could pass and then an exception would still appear.

I'd use the try catch to be safe (unhandled null pointer exceptions are something that should be avoided) but also try to find the race condition and if possible or manageable within a overseeable amount of time fix or handle that.

You could also wait a few ms and retry for a set amount of times if an exception appears to bypass the race condition (not very pretty but works).

Answer (score 0):

> I found a null pointer exception in the developers console which **never happened** to be and my **guess** it is a rare race condition

That sounds like a bug and just catching the exception sounds like you intend to ignore the bug instead of fixing it. Find out where these null values come from and fix it, don't let null pointers propagate to code that can't deal with them.

Comment: I would love to. But I can't reproduce the error. All I have is a stack trace from the customer device. And I am at a loss how it can be that reset is called before init (that are the two function in question). And the value is written only once — in init and no where else.